# is it safe to generate Diceware passwords client side

Tags: security, passwords, client-server

Currently generating a diceware passed password in client side javascript (each client gets a Cryptographically secure pseudorandom seed).

```
var password = this.word() + this.separtor() + this.word() + this.separtor() + this.word();
```

Although the passwords generated pass all strength testers I could find, my concern is that an attacker will not simply brute force the password using character combinations but actually use my generator against me.

word() has only 6^4 = 1296 combinations

So the generator will only produce  1296*1296*1296
= 2,176,782,336 combinations.

I added seperators (24 combinations) 1296*24*1296*24*1296
= 1,253,826,625,536

The CGI limits user attempts but as always an attacker could have my password hashes offline.

Generating the password server side is only safer in so far as having the wordlist compiled which may still be relatively easy to retrieve (at least for an attacker who has my password hashes).

As I am trying to ensure the passwords are memorable I didn't wish to add a  special character at random into the passphrase, but that would force the attacker to try every character combination ?

p.s move this to crypto if its more suitable there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure passwords are memorable, you should go for [five](https://xkcd.com/936/) **dictionary** words separated by a space (or not at all).

You must also assume that the attacker has knowledge of the algorithm and of the word list.

If you take a word list of 10000 words (the [average vocabulary](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2013/05/vocabulary-size) of an 8 years old native English speaker) then you have 10000^5 = 10^20 combinations.

You can expect about 1000 passwords / second in a average online environment, which gives an umpthillion years exercice for the hacker. This is equivalent to a smaller-umpthillion years offline attack.